# Designing a Facebook-like icon bar at the top of the page

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to come up with an idea on how to create an app bar similar to the one in the Facebook app for WP8.1. This is a screen:

[image: Facebook status bar]

As you can see, that white bar with some buttons on it hides at the top of the screen. This is what I thought:

• Use a Grid or a Canvas for the body of the status bar

• Add all the buttons/stuff inside it and manage them on their own

• Add an eventHandler for the ViewChanged event of the ScrollViewer I have inside my page: if the user has panned down, animate the status bar. If the user has panned up, hide the status bar.

The problem I have is this: my first Idea was to use a DoubleAnimation on the Y Property of the TranslateTransform Property of my base Grid/Canvas.
The problem is that if I use that, the element will move above anything else that's on screen.
So for example, if I have a title inside my page, then this status bar and a ScrollViewer, if I try to translate the status bar up it will cover my title.
Another idea was to use a ThicknessAnimation to animate the upper Margin of my base Grid/Canvas, but on WinRT there isn't a ThicknessAnimation.
And other than that, I know that a ThicknessAnimation is never a good idea as it has to update the whole visualtree at each iteration.

Any ideas? I'm wondering how did they do that inside their app :D

Thanks!

Sergio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can research `Canvas.ZIndex` for arrange order control to get the top bar to be on top of the second bar. You can also try the `Clip` property.

Comment: It worked :D
I created a class that inherits from Canvas and I added some methods to handle the animations and to bind the object to a ScrollViewer.
I set the Canvas.ZIndex of my UIElement that needed to be above the status bar to 1 and now when I translate the canvas it correctly hides beneath it, thanks! :)